# Find the $\epsilon - \delta$ values for the continuous function - modified step function defined on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let the modified step function be defined on $[0,1]$ by :

$f(x) = \begin{cases}  
        \bigg( \dfrac {2^n+1}{2}\bigg )x  - \dfrac {2^n-1}{2^n} ; & n \in \mathbb N~~ , \dfrac {2}        {2^n+1} \le x \le \dfrac {1}{2^{n-1}} \\
      \dfrac{1}{2^n}; & n \in \mathbb N~, \dfrac {1}{2^n}\leq x\leq \dfrac {2}{2^n+1} \\
       0 & x=0 
   \end{cases} $

Then, find $\epsilon / \delta$ values  where $\epsilon, \delta$ signify the normal parameters in the definition of continuity of a function.

**Attempt:**

the above function is not clear to be visualized around $x=0$, I am not sure how to move next?

Could someone please tell me how to move forward.

Thank you for your help!